# Fetching list of items always times out after 60 seconds

Tags: swift, alamofire, promisekit

I am fetching a list of items using Alamofire and Promisekit. Some items take longer to get than others. I have set the timeout in `alamoFireManager` to 180 seconds, however 60 seconds after the first `getRemoteItem` is called, all the remaining calls for items which have not been fetched in the list will fall into the `print("IN FAIL 2")`.  The error reads `

> responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}))

The initial `getItems` call will call for each item in parallel which is where I am guessing the problem may be but I cant figure out a workaround for this or why the 180 second timeout is not respected.

```
func getItems(ids:[Int]) -> [Promise<Bool>] {
    let totalCount = ids.count
    
    return ids.map { index -> Promise<Bool> in
        return firstly {
            getRemoteItem(id: index, totalCount: totalCount)
        }
    }
}


func getRemoteItem(id:Int, totalCount:Int) -> Promise<Bool> {
    let headers = ["Authorization": "JWT \(userToken)"]
    return Promise { seal in

        let url = baseURL + "/api/items"
        let itemParams: Parameters = ["item_id": id]
        
        alamoFireManager!.request(URL(string: url)!, method: .post, parameters: itemParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let jsonObject = response.result.value {
                    firstly {
                        self.saveItemToLocalStorage(jsonObject: jsonObject as! [String: Any], responseData: response.data!, totalCount: totalCount)
                    }.done { status in
                        seal.fulfill(status)
                    }.catch { error in
                        seal.reject(error)
                    }
                } else if let error = response.error {
                    print("IN FAIL 1")
                    seal.reject(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("IN FAIL 2")
                seal.reject(error)
            }
        }
    }
}


private lazy var alamoFireManager: SessionManager? = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 180
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 180
    let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    return alamoFireManager
}()
```

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson question updated with error

Comment: You need to inspect the data you're getting back, I suspect the server is timing out after 60 seconds and returning an error page to you that isn't JSON.